# Sharepoint 2010 custom new form column validation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, validation, newform

I have a custom list and custom New Form created using Visual Studio. Now I wanted validated a `Amount` column whether the value is less a value from another List column. I also have `Newform.cs` file.

Is there someway I can write `Onclick` event for Save button in New Form and write C# code to validate the value.

Comment: Is the other list column also displayed on the New form?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Script Editor Web part to your page and use the PreSaveAction function to validate your form.
The presaveaction is called before save the item.

```
function PreSaveAction ()
{
     return true; // if you want to execute save functionality of the form.

     //return false ;//if you want to stop execution of save functionality of the form.
}
```

If you want to call some C# code to valide your field, I suggest you to call some WebMethod via $.Ajax from the presaveaction. (methods deployed within an application page)

Comment: Script Editor Web Part is available only in SP 2013 version,not in SP 2010.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Using Custom Field**

You can create a custom field

```
<Field ID="{2E325F77-DCDA-4384-95CF-7EB83CD2DAD9}"
         Name="MyCustomField"
         StaticName="MyCustomField"
         DisplayName="MyCustomField"
         Type="MyCustomField"/>
```

Now you can a `class` and override function `GetValidatedString`

```
public class MyCustomField : SPField //Replace SPField with you field type
{
    public MyCustomField(SPFieldCollection fields, string fieldName) : base(fields, fieldName)
    {
    }

    public MyCustomField(SPFieldCollection fields, string typeName, string displayName) : base(fields, typeName, displayName)
    {
    }

    public override string GetValidatedString(object value)
    {
        if (this.Required)
        {
            if (YOUR CUSTOM VALIDATION LOGIC)
            {
                throw new SPFieldValidationException("MESSAGE.");
            }
        }

        return base.GetValidatedString(value);
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - Use Event Receiver**

**Option 3 - Use JavaScript `PreSaveAction`**

Comment: Could you help me how to access the sharepoint list item with query to get a column and check value entered in the newform is less than query column value. Actually i have Netamount column in a list and the newform is in another list which also have Netamount. So i have to check whether the Netamount in newform is less than other Netamount.